# Background Image doesnt load because of quote in url

Tags: css

I'm trying to fix some issues on a project and the method that converts texts into url is broken. Some urls include quote mark, like `somethi'n.png`.

When using this image path as background image, it brokes css property and throws `invalid property value` warning

How can I make this work without fixing image paths (there are so many)

```
'<div style="background: url('+ad.featured_image+')" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let position = ad.featured_image.lastIndexOf('.');

ad.featured_image.substring(0,position).replace(/_/g, "")+ad.featured_image.substring(position)')"
```

It will remove the special charatcers in the path variable this one "somethi'n.png" will turn as somethin.png like that

Comment: brilliant idea. but I'm not sure there are two images on server with quote mark and without it